# MPMoviePlayerController MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen strangeness

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have the following code to play a video

```
 moviePlayer1 =[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:firstMovieURL1];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doneButtonClicked) name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification object:nil];
    [[moviePlayer1 view] setFrame: [self.view bounds]];  // frame must match parent view
    [self.view addSubview: [moviePlayer1 view]];

    [moviePlayer1 play];




-(void)doneButtonClicked
{
    NSLog(@"doneButtonClicked ...");

    [moviePlayer1 stop];
    [moviePlayer1.view removeFromSuperview];

}
```

If I use the above code my screen looks like this. I have to click on the little arrow icon and then the screen again to show controls (forward/backwards/done button)

[image]

so what I did was add this controlStyle to my code. I see all the buttons now as soon as the player is launched but and now my done button doesn't close the window instead it just pauses the movie. What happened?

```
moviePlayer1.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
[moviePlayer1 play];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you do it. God forbid if apple makes this logic any easy on us.

```
[[moviePlayer1 view] setFrame: [self.view bounds]];  // frame must match parent view
    [self.view addSubview: [moviePlayer1 view]];

    moviePlayer1.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;

    [moviePlayer1 prepareToPlay];
    [moviePlayer1 play];

    //use this instead
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doneButtonClicked:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];


-(void)doneButtonClicked:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSLog(@"doneButtonClicked ...");

    NSNumber *reason = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey];

    if ([reason intValue] == MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited)
    {

        // done button clicked!

        [moviePlayer1 stop];
        [moviePlayer1.view removeFromSuperview];

    }
}
```